# Feature detection of SVG direction attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, microsoft-edge, right-to-left

MS Edge has [this bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/101323/). I seems to ignore the `direction` attribute in SVG, so that setting it to "rtl" gives the same result as with "ltr" (see example in bug). The other major browsers seem to support it properly.

How can I do feature detection of this in Javascript?
I've tried:

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var supported = svg.style.direction !== undefined;
```

But `supported` returns true in Edge, even though it clearly is not the case.

Any suggestion on how to detect is `direction` in SVG is working well?

Comment: You'd need to find some attribute of an `svg` that changes when the `direction` is set to `rtl` that is different from when it is set to `ltr`. I'm not fluent enough in SVG or writng directions to tell you what that is, but you might try to find one that changes in browsers that do fully support `direction` and check for that... Maybe something to do with [the bug linked to the one in your question](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12133259/)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan is onto something there - I wonder if you could calculate something using, say, a hidden `<text>` element inside the svg.

Comment: Interesting suggestions, I'll give them a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a text object that contains some right to left text. Then get the dimensions of that text and see if it extends in the appropriate direction.

Something like:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
text.setAttribute("direction", "rtl");
text.textContent="X";
svg.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
var supported = text.getBBox().x < 0;
console.log("supported="+supported);
```

This returns `true` in Chrome and Firefox, and `false` in IE11 and Edge.

However, it does require that you append the SVG to a page.  Hopefully that is not a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks! I've slightly modified it removing the `svg` node right after setting `supported` with `svg.parentNode.removeChild(svg);` and using _ instead of X as text as it is a bit less intrusive. I'll wait some time to see if other answers come in before accepting this one.

Comment: It doesn't need to be visible. You could always just position it absolutely at a point off the screen. Or make it's opacity zero.